# Compute this integral (multivar. calc.)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

So i have the following question:

> Compute
> $$\int_{C}(x^2+y)dx + (z+x)dy + (x+2y)dz$$
> where $C$ is the intersection of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4 $ and the plane $x+y=z$

So my thoughts are to parametrise it to make get $$r(t) = 2cos(t) i + 2sin(t)j + (2cos(t) + 2sin(t) ) k$$

and then use this along with $r'(t)$ to calculate

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} F(r(t)) \cdot r'(t) dt $$

Which when I computed it all, came out to be $$-8\pi$$

> I was hoping someone could either verify this method, along with the answer or help me to find out the solution (through tips)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have parametrized the surface correctly but your answer is incorrect.

$r(t) = (2 \cos t,  2 \sin t, 2 \cos t + 2 \sin t)$

So, $dx = -2 \sin t \ dt, \ dy = 2 \cos t \ dt, \ dz = (-2 \sin t + 2 \cos t) \ dt$

$x^2 + y = 4 \cos^2 t + 2 \sin t, x + z = 4 \cos t + 2 \sin t, x + 2y = 2 \cos t + 4 \sin t$

So $\ \displaystyle  \int_C \ (x^2+y) \ dx + (z+x) \ dy + (x+2y) \ dz = \int_0^{2 \pi} (12 \cos 2t + 4 \sin 2t - 8 \cos^2t \ \sin t) \ dt = 0$

Comment: That was my first thought, for it to be 0 - thank you for clearing that!